# Why resistance of load resistor determines gain of common emitter amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, resistors, gain, common-emitter

Most schematics I saw take output signal from collector, not from load resistor. So why we are calculating gain by dividing load resistor by emitter stabilizer resistor (or re - equivalent dynamic emitter resistance)? My logic tells me that the bigger load resistor would be, the more voltage it will steal from transistor itself, and this way will decreases gain in voltage. But in reality totally opposite thing happens.

This confuses me greatly and inhibits my attempts at understanding how amplifiers work.

Comment: "Most schematic I saw": Schematics for **what**? Seen **where**? And: what's the *definition of a common emitter amplifier? And, voltage isn't "stolen", put what you think in a formula, and you basically have an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *So why we are calculating gain by dividing load resistor by emitter
>   stabilizer resistor*

What you can reasonably say about a common emitter amplifier that uses an emitter resistor: -

- The collector current and the emitter current are broadly equal in value for DC and AC signals.
- The AC (or signal) voltage at the emitter (across the emitter resistor) is very close in value to that signal voltage on the base (\$V_B\$)
- The AC (or signal) part of the emitter current is therefore the signal on the base divided by the emitter resistor (\$R_E\$). This is ohms law (I = V/R)

So, given that collector current is the same as emitter current (DC and AC) and we know that this current is: -

$$\dfrac{V_B}{R_E}$$

That then allows us to predict the signal voltage |magnitude| on the collector because it is that current multiplied by the collector resistor, \$R_C\$: -

$$V_C = R_C\cdot\dfrac{V_B}{R_E}$$

Therefore the voltage gain (magnitude) is: -

$$\dfrac{V_C}{V_B} = \dfrac{R_C}{R_E}$$

Comment: For my opinion, one should not forget to add that this is a rather rough consideration...which is not valid anymore for emitter resistors equal to or below - let`s say - 250 ohms. In this case, the gain error will be app. 10%. Why not using the correct formula for the gain: A=Rc/(1/gm+RE) ? Now, one can see the role of the transconductance gm=Ic/Vt (1/gm app. 25 ohms at room temperature).

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit to gain in a bipolar one-transistor resistive-load circuit.

I stumbled across this, decades ago, in developing a circuit synthesizer for ac-coupled bipolar amplifiers.

At room temperature, where the "q/kt" is 0.026, the maximum gain is

Max_gain = VDD / 0.026

Thus at 26 volts the max gain is 1,000x **IF** the collector-emitter voltage is biased to be nearly zero volts.

More realistically, you bias the Collector-emitter for VDD/2 for large "linear" voltage swings, and the maximum gain is

Max_gain is VDD / ( 2 * 0.026)

This equation merely acknowledges the maximum collector current is

- Imax = VDD / Rcollector
- transconductance = Imax / 0.026
- Gain = transconductance * Rcollector

[ignoring Early Voltage, and any load impedances including Cob]

For FETS, there are various degrees of freedom that prevent a simple prediction such as this. Yet FETs are very very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitive explanation:

Think of the transistor as drawing current through the collector resistor. The current varies as your input voltage varies. This current creates a voltage drop across the collector resistor. If you increase the value of that collector resistor, you increase the voltage drop, which means the voltage output changes more, i.e. larger voltage gain.

In reality the current going into the transistor comes through both the collector resistor and the load resistor, so the gain is actually determined by the parallel combination of the two, until you start bumping into the output impedance of the transistor itself.